# Compiling CoffeeScripts on SVN Pre-Commit

Tags: svn, coffeescript, pre-commit-hook

I am working on an application for a client.  The client will also be developing the app after I finish the project, so I need to make it easy for them to do so.  I have been using CoffeeScripts to write my JavaScript and then I compile them when I push them to my personal build server with an Ant script.

The Ant script calls `coffee -c js/*.coffee` which compiles all of the coffee files down to JS files with the same name.  I would like to do that same command in an SVN pre-commit hook.  I know that changing files with SVN hooks is a bad thing, but I assume that since I am not actually changing any files, but instead creating new ones, that this isn't classified as the big bad no-no that people claim.

I am not familiar with SVN at all (I usually use Git) and everything that I can find talks about python scripts and a tool called svnlook, but nothing actually explains it.

Comment: Why are you using SVN in the first place? You should be using the right tool for the job, and it seems like SVN is **NOT** the right tool.

Comment: Care to elaborate Austin... I don't want to be using SVN, but I need to track the files on there for my client.  It is their SVN server.  I would much rather be using Git, and truthfully Git would be easier, but I am given SVN and I am not just going to say "SVN is the wrong tool" without valid reason.

Comment: In that case, I'll revise my statement and say "SVN *pre-commit hooks* are *probably* not the right tool for the job". The intention of pre-commit hooks is to verify you're not putting bad code into version control, and various other **passive** functions. As a general rule, you should be versioning the *source* not the compiled output. Obviously in this case though, to your client, the compiled output *is* the source. Perhaps a better solution is to keep two repos: a coffeescript one for you, and a (compiled) javascript one for them.

Comment: For example: keep a git repo for your self, with the coffeescript, and a SVN working copy for them, with the javascript. Add a pre-commit-hook to the *git* repo that compiles the CS, and puts it in the SVN working copy. There are a few benefits of keeping separate repositories like that: (1) you keep the semantic distinction between source and output, versioning only what you care about; (2) you don't have to look at the JS, they don't have to look at the CS; (3) you can keep a detailed revision history in a tool you're familiar with, and leave the SVN commits to be more "coarse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't like your idea. svn commit is not intended to push compiled java scripts to some server.
What if your client would need to push the same java scripts to other server?

It's better you'll svn commit to do the job its intended to.

To solve you problem you could provide a **publish script** which will do:

- export svn repository to a new location
- compile coffescripts to js files
- publish js to host provided as argument to the publish script

The **publish script** of course should be in svn too :)

Comment: CoffeeScripp compiles down to javascript, not java.  The reason that I need to compile them is that I am only using SVN to get the code to my client.  They do not have the coffee compiler on their systems and don't want to go through the process of installing Node.js and CoffeeScript on their system, so the coffeescript is only beneficial to me and no one else.

Comment: PS I do have an Ant task that handles publishing (compiling coffeescripts, combining and minifying javascript), and if I could just call that task

Comment: @Dave I'm bit confused - what do you mean when you say: "The client will also be developing the app after I finish the project"? What "product" client will receive after you finish your part?

Comment: The product is a theme for a CMS engine (Mura CMS).  I am the only developer initially for the product as I get them started using the CMS.  The client is actually a development firm moving aware from their current CMS engine.  I am developing plugins and themes to get them moved into it and then that will start developing it themselves.